# Detect HTML Custom Element Missing

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Is there a way to detect if you try to include a custom element that doesn't exist?

I'm making use of LitElement (Polymer) and I'd like to be able to detect when I try to use a custom element that doesn't exist, ideally throwing an error when I do.

The default behavior seems to be to simply shrug and not really render anything, which makes it very easy to miss, especially for trivial elements. The most common cause of this is forgetting to import the file with the custom element declaration.

I know that unknown elements are type `HTMLElement` and I could walk through all of the trees to find them:

```js
const findUnknown = node => {
  const self = node.constructor === HTMLElement;
  const shadowRoot = node.shadowRoot && findUnknown(node.shadowRoot);
  const children = Array.from(node.children).reduce((r, child) => 
    r.concat(findUnknown(child)), []);
    
  return (self ? [node] : [])
    .concat(shadowRoot || [])
    .concat(children || []);
};

const unknown = findUnknown(document);

console.log(unknown);
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Good</p>
  <does-not-exist>Bad</does-not-exist>
  <p>Also Good</p>
  <what-is-this>Also Bad</what-is-this>
</div>
```

This works, but seems a bit clunky and it relies on the element being `HTMLElement`. I'm not sure if there are any edge cases where a valid element my be a direct instance of `HTMLElement`.

I'd also have to rerun this every time the DOM changes.

Are there any better ways, like with `querySelector()` or events?

---

Edit: My detection condition definitely doesn't work. The new HTML5 semantic elements like `main` don't have a custom class and their constructor is `HTMLElement`, so they register as "unknown".

Edit 2: I did a comparison of all properties between `<main>` and a legitimately unknown element and I didn't find any that would indicate one is really unknown and one isn't. I think at this point, for those elements, I'm just going to have to explicitly exclude them with my above solution.

Comment: You could create a whitelist of valid HTML & custom elements and check `nodeName` against it. Not really great (hence the comment), but the HTML specs do have indexes of the elements in them you can scrape easily.

Comment: That's pretty much the approach I'm sitting on right now. My custom elements are all not HTMLElement but something else, so I just have to whitelist the semantic HTML5 elements I use. Not too bad to maintain by hand.

Comment: Can you check the tag name? Custom elements must have a hyphen in their name, so you can filter out anything without one. Seems simpler than building your own whitelist.

Comment: The problem is many custom elements are going to be valid because I implemented them. The goal is to find custom elements which I didn't implement. Also, I'm only adding to the whitelist as I use them. So far, I have like 3 elements on it, so not that bad. Also, if I added an element named "onewordoops" I would want to detect that as not implemented even though it is missing the hyphen.